# How to fix error "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError" on MacOS?

Tags: java

I am trying to run a java file using the command

```
java -jar BlueMap-3.14-cli.jar
```

but that leads to an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: de/bluecolored/bluemap/cli/BlueMapCLI has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:620)
```

I am using MacOS 13.4 (22F66) and `java -version` says `java version "1.8.0_371"`.

I am NOT an java expert and assume I have to update java? How to do that in the MOST SIMPLE POSSIBLE way, ideally using only command line commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install a more recent version of Java - Java 11 or later.

##### How to install Java 17

It's easiest to use Homebrew, a package manager for MacOS, to install packages on MacOS:

```
brew install openjdk@17
```

This requires Homebrew to be installed first. You can find the instructions here: [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/)

##### What Java version to install

To be specific, class file version 55 refers to Java 11. That's the minimum version you have to install. However, I recommend to install the latest long term support version that is **Java 17** currently.

If you are interested, you can find a table combining the class file versions with Java versions in [Chapter 4 "the class file format"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2) in the official documentation.