# Java Error java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: terminal, command-line, java

Trying to run

```
java -Xmx4G -Xms4G -jar launch.jar
```

but that leads to error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: launch.jar has been
compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this
version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
```

I found [this topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461260/how-to-fix-error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-on-macos) but solution **doesn't change anything**.

Using macOS 13.4 (22F66); Java version is 1.8.0_371, tried to install Java 17 with Homebrew `brew install openjdk@17`

Do you have any answer to this, ideally by using only command lines as in [1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461260/how-to-fix-error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-on-macos) ?

Comment: Relaunch system do not change anything.

Comment: The latest OpenJDK is 20.  Why would you go with such an old version of Java when the error message specifically states "it was compiled with a more recent version of Java"?

Comment: Thanks, trying with brew install openjdk@20.

Comment: Same error in output. Do you know if there is a way to force shell to execute with this version of openjdk ?

Comment: what do you get with `which java`

Comment: Path : "/usr/bin/java"

Comment: You're using the java that shipped with macOS.  You need to add the path to the java you just installed.  I don't use `brew` so I don't know the path off hand.

Comment: found it, ~/Users/USER/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/86433be4853b97a831d0c365e25b5536dc65d92f9c05682b9496f099bfe3d410--openjdk--20.0.1.ventura.bottle.tar.gz

Comment: That's the cache (temp storage) from where the formula/cask will be installed.  It will be something like `/usr/local/blah/blah/blah`.  Are you using Intel or Silicon?  Try `/opt/homebrew/bin`

Comment: Intel : /usr/local/Homebrew/ but after i don't find it in the folder.

Comment: type `sudo find /usr/local -name java` to search for the java binary.  I use MacPorts on both Intel and Silicon so I am not readily familiar with Brew's file structure.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/20.0.1/bin/java` ?

Comment: That might be it.  Issue that exact line as you see it as a command but append `--version`

Comment: It return `openjdk 20.0.1 2023-04-18`
`OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 20.0.1)`
`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 20.0.1, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: That's your new java.  Try running your `jar` with that java and see if it works.

Comment: Do not change everything - I think it still use by default macOS java.

Comment: You used the command `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/20.0.1/bin/java  foobar.jar`?  (Whatever your filename is)

Comment: No - i used it, return `Error : impossible to found main class foobar.jar
At : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foobar.jar`

Comment: I found this.  You might have to set your java environment variables:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309664/4703819

Comment: Wait...did you literally use `foobar.jar`?  That's a placeholder for whatever jar file you actually want to run.

Comment: As file name ? No - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463297/java-error-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror?noredirect=1#comment683179_463297